# on hovering change the icon

Tags: html, css, angular7

I have this nav bar icons as follows , and on hovering I want to show a different icons , means same icon in blue color bootstrap icon can not be used due to license issues. So what can be done on hovering to change the icon to alerts_torqHover.png

```html
<div class="topbaricons">
  <img src="assets/icons/alerts_torq.png">
  <a><img src="assets/icons/alerts_torqHover.png"> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need the first icon to be a non-link and the 2nd icon to be a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by CSS, and it will support on all browser.

```css
.topbaricons a {
  display: none;
}

.topbaricons:hover>img {
  display: none;
}

.topbaricons:hover a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbaricons">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/99e96b1a821a2ec12f52ea44b54f302a?s=48&d=identicon">
  <a><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/78c6fbe63bd0e401d22875c1937cc2a3?s=64&d=identicon"> </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend something like this. Even if you need it to link somewhere else, just put the img tag in the anchor as they won't be able to click without hovering anyway.

**On img tag**

```css
img:hover {
  content: url("http://placecage.com/c/480/240")
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placecage.com/c/240/120" />
```

**On class**

```css
.hover-change:hover {
  content: url("http://placecage.com/c/480/240")
}
```

```html
<img class="hover-change" src="http://placecage.com/c/240/120" />
```

Comment: Hi , I tried creating a class for my image and tried this 
 .alerttorq:hover {
    content:url("./assets/icons/alert_icon_selected.svg");   
}, but its not hovering , img is generic rite. can you say something for class specific

Comment: you can use **img.myClass:hover {}**

Comment: I added an example using class

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this with `:hover` class

```css
.topbaricons:hover .mango {
  display: block;
}

.topbaricons:hover i,
.topbaricons:hover .orange {
  display: none;
}

.mango,
.orange {
  display: none;
}

i,
.orange {
  display: block;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbaricons">
  <img class="mango" src="http://www.twentyonepilots.com/sites/g/files/g2000004896/f/Sample%202_0.jpg">
  <img class="orange" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51TcdS9z2fL._SY300_QL70_.jpg">
  <i class="userName" style=" margin-left: 15px">ICON</i>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi , is it possible to change two images,I mean on hover I need to show image1 and without hovering will see image2. How can i achieve it